# Flink Connector Kafka: user properties.auto.offset.reset in group-offsets mode

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

flink-version:1.14.2

kafka-version:3.0

flink-cluster:local

When I am using flink-sql with properties 'scan.startup.mode'='group-offsets',the create table sql like this:

> create table kafka(String a,String b) with
> ('scan.startup.mode'='group-offsets','properties.auto.offset.reset'='latest','properties.group.id':'test'
> ...)

And I received some warnings when I commit the mission in local mode:
[2022-02-16 09:52:58] [WARN ] --Property auto.offset.reset is provided but will be overridden from latest to none
[2022-02-16 09:52:58] [WARN ] --Property auto.offset.reset is provided but will be overridden from latest to none

And the task has throw an exception:

> org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.NoOffsetForPartitionException:
> Undefined offset with no reset policy for partitions

I found the method

> KafkaSourceBuilder::parseAndSetRequiredProperties

will cover the properties **auto.offset.reset** to **startingOffsetsInitializer.getAutoOffsetResetStrategy().name().toLowerCase()**
[properties will be override](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtCak.png)

How can i use the properties auto.offset.reset in group-offsets mode?
I truly appreciate you help!

Comment: I recall a github issue saying auto offset reset wasn't able to be set in the sql runner. Maybe that was in Apache Beam, though

Comment: thanks! I write a method that initialize the offsets before commit a task

Comment: This is a known issue in Flink, see: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-24697 Flink v 1.15.0 will be release soon and this issue be fixed.

@Xontrol have you found a workaround for that?

Comment: grateful! I had to use kafka-client to initialize the offset before submitting the task